# import module from working directory not working

Tags: python

I've looked at all other similar posts and applied what was suggested but nothing worked so far

```
from test import *

dir(test)
```

This throws the following error message:

> NameError: name 'test' is not defined

I made sure that the file is in the same working directory. Using jupyter lab currently

I also changed the "*" for specific functions within my test.py file but to no avail.

Comment: `from test import *` imports everything from within test, but not test itself as a module. For that you can do `import test` and then to reference things within it just do `test.thing`.

Comment: but theoretically from test import * should work? So youre saying , I cant call the module anymore after "from test import *" but the function within? @L.MacKenzie

Comment: Yes, so if you have a function `func1` inside test you can still do `from test import *` and then just call `func1()`.

Comment: @L.MacKenzie it worked. thank you , how to accept your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you havn't import `test` module with your import statement. try below:

```
import test

dir(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your are running the script from your project forlder. In other words make sure your project folder is in the import path:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Your project folder must be in the path list in order to be able to import it.